# Prove that one integer among $m$ consecutive integers is divisible by $m$

Tags: number-theory

Show that of any $m$ consecutive integers, exactly one is divisible by $m$. I am finding it difficult to prove that there is only one number among $m$ consecutive integers that is divisible by $m$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the numbers be $b_r=a+r, 0\le r\le m-1$

**Existence**:

We can apply [Pigeonhole Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) to prove the existence by contradiction.

Let none of them is divisible by $m,$ so they can leave $m-1$ distinct remainder$(r)$s namely, $1\le r\le m-1$

But, as there are $m$ numbers, so at least tow of them leave the same remainders.

Let $b_u,b_v$ leave the same remainders where $1\le u<v\le m-1$

Then $m$ divides $b_v-b_u=v-u$

But, $0<v-u<m-1$ can not be divisible by $m$

**Uniqueness**:

If $m$ divides both $b_s,b_t,0\le s\le t\le m-1$

$m$ must divide $b_t-b_s=t-s$ which lies $\in(0,m-1]$ which is impossible

So, there can be at most one $r$ divisible by $m$

Comment: Did you prove existence? Or just uniqueness?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee, Updated. Thanks for your observation

Comment: I don't think it's actually the pigeonhole principle, since there are $m$ things in $m$ boxes (as opposed to $m+1$ things in $m$ boxes) and we're trying to show that each box has one thing (instead of at least one box having two things).

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee, Let none of them is divisible by $m$. Then there can be $m-1$ distinct remainders $1\cdots m-1$ by $m$  $b_r$s

Comment: Okay, you should add this to the answer, +1

Comment: Please explain how to use pegionhole principle to prove existence.

Comment: @PranavA.R, Hope you don't have any confusion as you accepted the answer

Comment: I understood how to prove that only a unique number among m consecutive numbers is divisible by m . But , how is the pigeonhole principle applied to confirm the existence of such a number ?

Comment: @PranavA.R, Please find the edited version

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

Any integer can be written one of $m$ numbers: $km,km+1,\cdots, km+(m-1)$